# Loading screen/dialog in SWT application

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I am writing an application that are loading datas from a database.. In that time the GUI stucks, because I am only using one thread.

So, I want to improve my app by adding a loading dialog such as (I know its PHP ;) :P )[image]

But I am not so familiar with threading issues..

My code from the LoadingDialog so far:

```
    import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

    public class LoadingView extends Dialog {

        protected Object result;
        protected Shell shell;
        private Label labelText;

        /**
         * Create the dialog.
         * 
         * @param parent
         * @param style
         */
        public LoadingView(Shell parent, int style) {
            super(parent, style);
        }

        public void upadteLabel(String neuerText) {

            labelText.setText(neuerText);
        }

        public void kill() {

            shell.dispose();
        }

        /**
         * Open the dialog.
         * 
         * @return the result
         */
        public Object open() {
            createContents();
            shell.open();
            shell.layout();
            Display display = getParent().getDisplay();
            while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                    display.sleep();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        /**
         * Create contents of the dialog.
         */
        private void createContents() {
            shell = new Shell(getParent(), getStyle());
            shell.setSize(349, 80);
            shell.setText(getText());

            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(shell, SWT.INDETERMINATE);
            progressBar.setBounds(10, 10, 323, 17);

            labelText = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
            labelText.setBounds(10, 33, 323, 15);

        }
```

How do I have to invoke this dialog from my "main application"/main thread?

I have the GUI loop of my main application. And in this thread I have to invoke the GUI loop from the LoadingDialog, right? And in an extra thread I  call the database loading method an from this I am updating the dialogs text (such as "Loading XYZ", then "Loading XYZ2" ...) with

```
Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
```

Maybe you know an good example for that in the web.. Because I couldn't find anything exactly like that... :/

Thanks for your help!!